# change background color of video iPad/iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

with the following method I play a video:  (using the #import  framework)

MPMoviePlayerController *player;

```
-(IBAction) playMovie: (NSString*) videoName ViedeoType:(NSString*) videoType{

  ViewVideoSubview.alpha = 0;

  NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                   pathForResource:videoName 
                   ofType:videoType];

  player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
  [ViewVideoSubview addSubview:player.view];
  ....
  ....
}
```

and the video plays fine. I am wondering if it possible to change the background color of the video from black to white?

the video plays in the black rectangle:

[image]

I have tried stuff like `player.backgroundView.alpha = 0;` but that has not worked.

EDIT :

I have also tried:

```
[[player backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and that changes the background color but the area between the video and the player.view

Comment: Good question. I've also found impossible to set properties on the background view of a movie player, so you're not alone. I home someone is able to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: I might not be interpreting this question correctly, but I doubt that it is possible to do something like this.  Almost no video formats support transparency, so if a video has a black background or something of that nature, you will not be able to change its color in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, hence I am uncertain if my answer matches...

To change the color of the video-view that is showing as long as the movie is not yet fully loaded/playing:

```
player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

**Note**: It is not possible to change part of the encoded video data without reencoding the video itself.

Comment: But that black color appears only when de video is about to play. When it loads it has white on the background. by default all videos behave this way.

Comment: Also when the video finishes playing and I already release it it shows a black rectangle. how can I make that rectangle white so that when my video finish playing it has the same color as the background.

Comment: So to spell it out in other words - what you are seeing is: Movie-Player-View not showing (yet) -> white background, Movie-Player-View showing but movie still loading -> white background, Movie-Player-View loading is in a state that playback may begin -> black background. If that is the case then I can confirm that this is a normal behavior. You will see that black background for like 0.5 seconds max but you will see it.

Comment: yeah and I was wondering if it is possible to see white instead of black. My temporary solution was to make the alpha of that view equal to 0 and then play the video wait 1 second then make the alpha equal to 1. But at the end when the video finish playing it shows black for another second. I am playing the video on a white background making it look like an animation that's why I am interested in this question.

Answer (score 0):

`moviePlayerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]`

UPD: the only thing that I can recommend is switching to low level AV Foundation. You will be able to control all the layers you need.

Comment: I posted that on my Edit long time ago to mention that I wanted to change the black color of the video when it is about to play and when it finishes...

Comment: Well, I answered way before your edit. Don't see why downvote. Consider Alex Nichol's comment on your question.

Comment: @Tono Nam I am afraid you are mixing things up - Anton and me, we both suggested changing the view.backgroundColor and NOT the backgroundView.backgroundColor - there is a difference!

Comment: I am not mixing things up. Do that and you are still going to have a black rectangle with white outside of it.  The area where the video plays is black. If I use your code I will get white outside the video. Try it yourself. Tell me if you still get white when the video  finishes playing or when is it about to load. When the video is playing this is not a problem and it will not make sense to attempt to change any background. But when the video finish playing it shows a black rectangle regardless if I use your code or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the background color, after adding the playerController into the current view hierarchy insert the code below:

```
NSArray *subViews = [[[self playerController] view] subviews];
for(UIView *v in subViews)
{
    if([v respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)])
    {
        [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}
```